# HERE MAPS API - speed limit with multiple waypoints

Tags: here-api

Is it possible to get LinkInfo(especially SpeedLimit) for more than one waypoint?

I have a request like this:

https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/getlinkinfo.xml?app_id=App_id&app_code=app_code&mode=car&waypoint=52.230136,20.978028&linkattributes=all

and it works fine for me, but I want to get more data at once.

Comment: This might not be possible using getLinkInfo , as an alternative you could try using the Platform Data Extension API which provides data in tiles so you could request Speed Limits in a Tile & Layer (SPEED_LIMITS_FCn is the layer for Speed Limits). Some documentation links https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/key-concepts.html    https://developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/platform-data/topics/example-tiles.html

Comment: Thanks, I will see to this. I found also this: https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/rme_pde_speeding_along_gps_trace. And it's really what I need, but can't find samples to do that...

Answer (score 0):

As per our earlier answer which was
"This might not be possible using getLinkInfo , as an alternative you could try using the Platform Data Extension API which provides data in tiles so you could request Speed Limits in a Tile & Layer (SPEED_LIMITS_FCn is the layer for Speed Limits). Some documentation links developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/… developer.here.com/platform-extensions/documentation/…"